# SQL Server 2014 C# triggers

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Here is what I would like to do:

- insert item into a SQL Server 2014 table
- have a trigger that will execute some C# code
- C# code will perform work on item and write result to file

I've found older SQL articles on CLR triggers, but I was wondering what the "latest and greatest" way to achieve something like this is?  I found one article that discusses using the SQL service broker, and then pull work items from that.  Is this a good approach?

I've never developed for SQL Server before, so I'm not really sure what I should be searching for to help me out.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254956(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I did come across that, but saw it was an older article for .NET 2.0.  I'm trying to figure out if there are newer techniques or best practices; maybe in the 4.5 framework... Nothing has really come up, but I don't know what I should be searching for.

Comment: Does the work need to happen synchronously? If not, I'd suggest using Service Broker with external activation. The idea being that in your trigger, you pop a message into a SB queue and an external program is monitoring the queue and will do the work at a later point. That way, you don't need to grant the SQL account any special permissions (in your case, to an external file system).